# Flash CameraUI orientation is wrong

Tags: ios, flash, camera

We're developing an AIR app for android and iOS. An important part of the app is taking photos. Using `flash.media.CameraUI` works perfectly on android, but we experience problems on iOS.

In the iOS camera application, when we rotate the iPad, the orientation is wrong: If we rotate the pad clockwise, the image is rotated anticlockwise. The UI buttons have the correct orientation though, and when the photo is taken, the resulting bitmap has the right orentation based on the orientation of the camera, not the actual view on the screen.

Looking at different camera apps, I notice that when the pad is rotated so the orientation changes clockwise, the camera does three things: First, the displayed image immediately becomes rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise (so it looks wrong). Then, the image slowly rotates 90 degrees clockwise, to restore the correct orientation. In addition, the UI buttons change orientation so the text is displayed correctly.

It seems as in our app, it only rotates the image slowly without doing the first immediate rotation. Thus, the end result is wrong.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found that the issue isn't just restricted to AIR.
[UIImagePickerController camera view rotating strangely on iOS 8 (pictures)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932642/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-view-rotating-strangely-on-ios-8-pictures)