# Ipad camera in 90 degree rotated

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I've a landscape Ipad app (and portrait in iPhone) that opens up the camera to take a photo always rotated of 90 degrees.
It will happen since iOS 8.x.
the code is:

```
  [self.importPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.avatarImageView.frame
                                                             inView:self.avatarImageView
                                           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                           animated:YES];
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Do you look on photos in Xcode using fast previewer?

Comment: The shooted photo comes in the right orientation. The problem is while shooting, I see what's camera dsee but rotated of 90 degrees

Comment: It's IOS-8 bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932642/